# using OCaml to simplify arithmetic expression

Tags: ocaml

I am now using ocaml to deal with some arithmetic expressions. If every arithmetic expression is a string like: "1+2*(2-5)". I want to know how to use ocaml to eliminate useless parentheses.

For example if we get a string like "(2*(1-8))" we should output "2*(1-8)".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OCaml is just a programming language, not a symbolic algebra system. So you would solve this in OCaml just as in any general purpose language.

A full blown solution would be to parse the expression into a tree, then walk the tree to produce the output. For this you need to analyze your string lexically (for which you can probably use the `Str` module), and then parse the tokens. You can code your own parser pretty easily, or you could really go full force and use a parser generator like `ocamlyacc`.

For the relatively simple problem of reparenthesizing an arithmetic expression you can use a variant of the ["shunting yard"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm, which in essence calculates a canonical, unparenthesized (RPN) form of an expression.